# XSLT :How to set a value of a variable in one xls file and use the same variable in another xls file. Global variable in XSLT concept

Tags: xml, xslt

Question:
How to set a value of variable in one xls file and use it another xls file. Global variable in XSLT:
I am trying to set a value of a variable in one template in A.XSL file and trying to use the same variable in B.XLS file but getting multiple error.
Is it technically possible to set a global variable in one file and use it in another file in XSLT?

I am beginner in XLS.

Comment: There are global variables and parameters in XSLT, just declare e.g. `<xsl:variable name="foo" select="'bar'"/>` as a top level element (i.e. child of `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`) and you can reference `$foo` anywhere in your XSLT code, including in modules that include or import that stylesheet module where you declared the variable. But your whole question seems to be about two issues, global variables, and having several or at least two XSLT modules, while you never show or explain in which way you try or want to combine the two XSLT documents. So explain that in some more detail.

Comment: Thanks Martin, Can the value be set in File A as <xsl:variable name="foo" select="'bar'"/> and can variable be used in File B as $foo . Just want to add that foo is being set dynamically in file A and whatever the value it would have, i need to use in File B.

Comment: As a global variable or parameter (i.e. the `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param` as a direct child of the stylesheet's root `xsl:stylesheet`, I think, yes, you can do that. Not from inside a template, however.

Comment: When i call the variable $foo from File B, Its value is coming as NULL. I am new XSLT. Can you guide me with Pseudo code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of a global variable within a template. That's not how variables work in declarative languages. You need to do some basic reading about the concepts of the language: any XSLT textbook or tutorial should explain this.

Please recast your question to describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the code you are trying to write in your solution. If we know what problem you are trying to solve (that is, the input, the output, and how they relate to each other) then we can guide you to solving it with XSLT.

Comment: My problem is this : I have a folder "ABC" which has two XSLT Files in it . one is Z1.XSLT and other is Z2.XSLT.  Z1.XSLT has a variable V1 which has value "TEST" and i am calling V1 in Z2.XSLT and getting NULL value returned for V1 in Z2.XSLT.            I am using <xsl:value-of select="$v1"/> to print the value of V1 in Z2.XSLT but it is coming as NULL.                                            I am setting teh value of V1 in Z1.XSLT as <xsl:variable name="v1">TEST</xsl:variable>

Comment: That's not a description of the problem your application is trying to solve, that's a description of the code that doesn't work.